# Programming In SQLITE

Tags: database, sqlite

In college I learned PL/SQL, which I used to insert/update data into table programmatically.

So is there any way to do it in SQLITE?

I have one table book which has two columns: `readPages` and `currentPage`. `readPage` contains info about how many pages I've read today and `currentPage` shows total read pages till today.

Currently I have data for only `readPages` so I want to calculate `currentPage` for past days, e.g.

```
readPages:   19  10  43  20  35   # I have data for 5 days
currentPage: 19  29  72  92  127  # I want to calculate it
```

So this can be easy with programming, but how to do with sqlite as it is not like plsql.

[image: Table Schema And data]

Comment: An important difference here is that PL/SQL runs on a separate server. Latency between the server and the application is significant enough that it's worthwhile to execute code directly on the SQL server in order to get decent performance for certain things. Now, SQLite is a library embedded inside an application. There is no significant latency here. So… why do this in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the rows can be determined by `id` or by `date`.
The problem with the column `date` is that its format: `'DD-MM'` is not comparable. 
Better change it to something like: `'YYYY-MM-DD'`.
Since your version of SQLite does not allow you to use window functions, you can do what you need with this:

```
update findYourWhy 
set currentPage = coalesce(
  (select sum(f.readPage) from findYourWhy f where f.id <= findYourWhy.id), 
  0
);
```

If you change the format of the `date` column, you can also do it with this:

```
update findYourWhy 
set currentPage = coalesce(
  (select sum(f.readPage) from findYourWhy f where f.date <= findYourWhy.date), 
  0
);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kzEQHTrBR62aqwsuG8p67V/0).

```
CREATE TABLE findYourWhy (
    id  INTEGER,
    date    TEXT,
    currentPage INTEGER,
    readPage    INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
INSERT INTO findYourWhy (id,date,currentPage,readPage) VALUES 
 (1,'06-05',null,36),
 (2,'07-05',null,9),
 (3,'08-05',null,12),
 (4,'09-05',null,5),
 (5,'10-05',null,12),
 (6,'11-05',null,13),
 (7,'12-05',null,2),
 (8,'13-05',null,12),
 (9,'14-05',null,3),
 (10,'15-05',null,5),
 (11,'16-05',null,6),
 (12,'17-05',null,7),
 (13,'18-05',null,7);
```

Results:

```
| id  | date  | currentPage | readPage |
| --- | ----- | ----------- | -------- |
| 1   | 06-05 | 36          | 36       |
| 2   | 07-05 | 45          | 9        |
| 3   | 08-05 | 57          | 12       |
| 4   | 09-05 | 62          | 5        |
| 5   | 10-05 | 74          | 12       |
| 6   | 11-05 | 87          | 13       |
| 7   | 12-05 | 89          | 2        |
| 8   | 13-05 | 101         | 12       |
| 9   | 14-05 | 104         | 3        |
| 10  | 15-05 | 109         | 5        |
| 11  | 16-05 | 115         | 6        |
| 12  | 17-05 | 122         | 7        |
| 13  | 18-05 | 129         | 7        |
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much but i dont know how coalesce()function work.

Comment: `coalesce()` returns the 1st non null of its arguments. In this case, if the sum is null, it returns 0. If you are sure that this sum will never be null, you can omit coalesce and use: `update findYourWhy set currentPage = (select sum(f.readPage) from findYourWhy f where f.id <= findYourWhy.id);`

Comment: Oh i get it now.I do same thing another way.                                                        **UPDATE findYourWhy set currentPage = readPage where id=1;**                                                                                                                                          
**update findYourWhy set currentPage = readPage + ( SELECT currentPage from findYourWhy f where findYourWhy.id -1 = f.id ) where findYourWhy.id>1;**

Comment: Why? The 1st UPDATE will unnecessarily update all the rows with readPage from 1st row. Why do you execute 2 updates? Also, you can't be sure that the ids will always differ by 1. If id is autoincrement and you delete rows, there will be gaps.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using sqlite 3.25 or newer, something like:

```
SELECT date, readPages
      , sum(readPages) OVER (ORDER BY date) AS total_pages_read
FROM yourTableName
ORDER BY date;
```

will compute the running total of pages.

Comment: @thesummer *If you're using sqlite 3.25 or newer*. You're using an outdated version that lacks window functions.

Comment: I am really sorry for it i didn't checked it. So shall i delete question?